# Does an adjective change meaning in “in length”?

Tags: adjectives

When an adjective is used in structure “ in length “ as is the case with sentence below, does it change it's meaning ?

> We can cut lumbers into 5 meters in longest length .

If this sentence are wrong ,please correct me .

Comment: "lumbers" with an "s" is simply totally wrong.  You cut *planks* to length.  The word "lumbers" does not exist (except in very unusual situations).

Comment: Note that timber (softwood anyway) tends to come in a variety of standard sizes from 1.8m to 6.3m. It would be quite limiting to be unable to provide timber in a length of less than 5m.

Comment: What are you asking? In the first sentence, you say that 5 meters is the *longest* length, but in your second sentence you say it's the *minimum* length. The words *longest* and *minimum* have essentially opposite meanings.

Comment: I deleted second one . I realized later . My fault. I asked if the use of in longest length correct or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think "lumber" is a non-countable noun, and "timber" is both countable and non-countable, but that may be an American English difference if that's what you're learning.

"We can cut lumber to 5 metres longest length" means (a) they can cut to less than 5 metres, and (b) some pieces will be shorter than 5 metres.

"We can cut timber into minimum of 5 metres" means they **can't** cut timber *shorter* than 5 metres -- the opposite to above.

Answer (score 3):

The reason we say, for example, "5 metres *in length*" is to show that the measurement of 5 metres is the length and not any other dimension such as width. We don't always prefix "length" with "in".

You are right in saying that "lumber" and "timber" are non-countable nouns, but "*a length*" can be used as a noun for a specific cut of timber, the plural of which is "*lengths*".

So you could say:

> We can cut timber into 5-metre minimum *lengths*.*

<sub>*you have to be careful this does not sound like you mean 5 lengths of one metre each, because a 1-metre length can be called "a metre length".</sub>

or

> We can cut timber into lengths no shorter than 5 metres.

(these are using "length" as a noun for the piece of cut timber)

**or**

> The minimum length we can cut timber into is 5 metres.

(this is using "length" as a noun for the measurement)

Comment: @Justin Quite right, corrected.